# Trouble setting up multidomain SSL in IIS 7?

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, godaddy

We have purchased a multidomain SSL with common name "**www.smartitlens.com**"
and have a two Subject Alternative Names(SAN) added

1. Utilities
2. project

and i have added bindings.
But when i try to access subdomains in HTTPS, i am getting following warning in browser

**Server's certificate does not match the URL**
[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create **Subject Alternative Names(SAN)** as full subdomain

Example: **subdomain.domain.com**